# contact form redirect when url rewriting rule enabled

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i made a form contact with header Location redirection after form validation.
Every things works fine when url are like this

`mysite.com/index.php?p=contacts`  --->> with

```
header('Location: index.php?p=contacts'); in post_contact.php
```

but afer adding this rule in .htaccess,

```
RewriteRule ^(en_US|fr_FR)/([^\?]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&p=$2 [NC]
```

redirection in post_contact.php doesn't work anymore

```
header('Location: index.php?p=contacts');
```

may someone try to give me some help

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work anymore` ? You'll have to provide more information about it because i can't see any conflict between your rule and your pages

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch seeother ^/$  http://example.com/fr_FR/accueil
RewriteRule ^(en_US|fr_FR)/([^\?]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&p=$2 [NC]

Comment: header('Location: index.php?p=contacts'); sent me to http://example.com/fr_FR/post_contact.php                         this after adding     RewriteRule ^(en_US|fr_FR)/([^\?]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&p=$2 [NC]  @Justinlurman

Comment: How on earth do you get a redirect to `/fr_FR/post_contact.php` ? Your rule rewrites it to `index.php` so that's not the main problem. Guess it's a problem using relative paths instead of absolute paths but it's almost impossible to know it without other information. How do you go to `post_contact.php` at first ? Is this by a form submit ?

Comment: yes @Justinlurman, form submit <form action="post_contact.php" method="POST" id="formulaire">

Comment: When you're on this form, what url do you see before submitting ?

Comment: http://example/fr_FR/contacts

Comment: Ok that's what i thought. It's a relative path problem. Just replace `action="post_contact.php"` with `action="/post_contact.php"` and it will be ok. You should use absolute paths for everything (html resources, links, etc). That would prevent you from this type of errors when dealing with *mod_rewrite* and virtual folders

Comment: right @Justinlurman it works form is sent but i will try to change header('Location: index.php?p=contacts'); to something else for matching redirected url type.

Comment: no way @JustinIurman, i changed header('Location: index.php?p=contacts'); to header('Location: example/fr_FR/contacts'); in order to be redirected to 
 example/fr_FR/contacts    but nothing

Comment: `header('Location: /fr_FR/contacts');`

Comment: yes @Justin already try but i think to something like this <code>header("Location: /$lang/contacts");</code> with $lang = en_US|fr_FR ( virtual folders from url rewrite)

Comment: So what's the problem ?

Comment: thanks for help @Justin, finally ok header("Location: /$lang/contacts"); with $lang = $_COOKIE['lang']; THANKS